# Keep one sprite within the screen but let others move off

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game where the user moves a spaceship around and fires bullets. I want to make it so that the user cannot move the spaceship off of the screen, but the when the bullets are fired, they can leave the screen. How can I do this? I have included a screenshot down bellow.

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {



    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    self.physicsBody = borderBody
    borderBody.friction = 0
    borderBody.restitution = 0

    Bullet.hidden = true


    buttonDirUp.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: -50)
    buttonDirUp.setScale(2.0)
    self.addChild(buttonDirUp)

    ship.setScale(0.33)
    shootButton.setScale(0.7)

    buttonDirLeft.position = CGPoint(x: -250, y: -100)
    buttonDirLeft.setScale(2.0)
    self.addChild(buttonDirLeft)

    buttonDirDown.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: -150)
    buttonDirDown.setScale(2.0)
    self.addChild(buttonDirDown)

    buttonDirRight.position = CGPoint(x: -150, y: -100)
    buttonDirRight.setScale(2.0)
    self.addChild(buttonDirRight)

    self.view?.multipleTouchEnabled = true

    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

    self.addChild(base)
    base.position = CGPointMake(200, -100)

    self.addChild(ball)
    ball.position = base.position

    self.addChild(ship)
    ship.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

    self.addChild(shootButton)
    shootButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: -100)

    ball.zPosition = 1
    base.zPosition = 0

    ball.alpha = 0.4
    shootButton.alpha = 0.4
    base.alpha = 0.4
    buttonDirRight.alpha = 0.4
    buttonDirLeft.alpha = 0.4
    buttonDirUp.alpha = 0.4
    buttonDirDown.alpha = 0.4

}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DFx5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can just set up nodes around the perimeter of the view, and use collisionBitMask of your space ship and set that equal to all of the nodes you established for the perimeter.

```
spaceShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.firstNode | PhysicsCategory.secondNode | PhysicsCategory.thirdNode | PhysicsCategory.fourthNode
```

Comment: I don't understand. I've just started using sprite kit

Comment: Can you post some of your code so I can get a feel of what you know and don’t know

Answer (score 0):

What you could do instead is create a function that checks to see if the sprite is greater than self.frame.width or self.frame.height, and if so, then position the sprite back at the bottom, and vice versa. Sort of how they do it in the game Pacman.

```
func updateSpritePosition() {
    if ship.position.x > self.frame.width {
        ship.position.x = 0
    }
    else if ship.position.x < 0 {
        ship.position.x = self.frame.width
    }
    else if ship.position.y > self.frame.height {
        ship.position.y = 0
    }
    else if ship.position.y < 0 {
        ship.position.y = self.frame.height
    }
}
```

You may have to play around with the numbers to get a smooth transition. But I hope this helps.

Comment: where should I call the function?

Comment: In override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) { }